# React native: TypeError: Network Request Failed

Tags: fetch, react-native

when I try to run the code below in chrome console it works and I get alert in the browser but when I try to run the same code inside react native environment, I get an error instead: "***TypeError: Network Request Failed***".

```
makeRequest(){
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => alert(data))
    .catch(e => alert(e));
}


render() {
     return(
         <View style = {styles.main}>
            {setTimeout(()=>this.makeRequest(),1000);}
         </View>
     )
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a request from your device?

Comment: on the android emulator

Comment: Looke that: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10404

Comment: thanks man, it was problem with localhost

Comment: you are welcome :D

Answer (score 1):

Use 10.0.2.2 IP Address instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

```
return fetch('http://<your ip>')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```